# Who exactly is the progenitor of Kāyasthas?

Tags: scripture, skanda-purana, ancestry, chitragupta

It is firmly believed that the Kāyasthas are descendants of Lord Citragupta who's the scribe of Yama Deva.
However, after going through the Skanda Purana's **Chapter 139 - Greatness of Citrāditya (Citra-āditya**), I got really confused about Kāyastha lineage.
There it is stated, *There was a great soul on earth called Mitra (a Kāyastha) whose son Citra was chosen by Yama as his scribe post receiving the boon from Surya Deva.*

Can anybody here please clear my confusion on **who exactly is the progenitor of Kāyasthas**?

Source: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc626927.html